# Modeling Techniques for Sales Forecasting

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, model

I am working on a sales forecast right now and I am not sure what type of model to use.

I have 17 Quarters of data(4 Full years + 1 QTR) and I am only looking to forecast 2 quarters into the future at maximum. My data is also very seasonal.

My only experience is using a simple multiple regression model, using the quarter number(to account for seasonality) and the time period as independent variables, which I worry wont be reactive enough to new data.

What model would be ideal for my scenario?

Comment: Your approach should consider identifying anomalies (pulses,level shifts,seasonal pulses ) while incorporating memory (arima structure) . Stay clear of any pre-specified form like holt-winters and allow the data to suggest the appropriate model.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably triple exponential smoothing (also called Holt-Winters), which you can use through the ETS() function the the R Forecast Package or with the Statsmodels library in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a Holt-Winters approach as well.  I just verified that a quick Google search brings numerous references. Feel free to post questions here too if you run into trouble.

Further, I would suggest comparing your forecast performance against a "No-Change" or a "Seasonal No-Change" model to verify you're adding value with your process.